# Cannot set resolution for HP LE2202x to recommended 1920x1080

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution

Cannot set my monitor (HP LE2202x) to the recommended resolution of 1920x1080.

The only options are:

1600x1200   1280x1024   1024x768   800x600

PC: HP Intel Core i7-3770 @3.40 GHz
8 GB RAM; 7.88 Usable

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

[computer display options/resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf3Ei.png)

Comment: What is the maximum resolution of the computer video driver ?